# Famous cases of multiple papers by the same author published in same issue of same journal

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, journals

I have been wondering if there are many cases of an author having published two (or more?) papers in the same issue of the same journal. I vaguely recall having seen one or two cases like this, maybe be old papers, but cannot vividly remember. I have the impression such a situation would make sense should the two papers be in the same topic, say, one is sort of a (substantial) continuation of the other, for instance (given the fact that in Mathematics there is some pressure against publishing too often in the same journal). I am of course asking this question for papers having a sole author (or maybe the same set of authors).

Comment: I've seen this with some frequency in the older analytic number theory literature.

Comment: In the very old times this must have been rather common as the number of journals was limited. Look e.g. at old volumes like this one of Crelle, 1844: https://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/toc/?PID=PPN243919689_0028 There you find four authors with more than one article, Eisenstein taking it to an extreme actually with 10 articles!

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Roger Howe famously filled an entire issue of Pacific Journal of Mathematics ([volume 73, no.2](//doi.org/10.2140/pjm.1977.73-2), 1977) with 8 different papers. (Also, Euler...)

Comment: Not the entire issue! There are also 3 small errata. (That's pretty amazing.)

Comment: That is really an interesting case, and the topics of the papers seem pretty close (only one of them has a co-author). It would be interesting to know how did that happen. Did he complete and submit the manuscripts simultaneously to PJM? And for what reason? I can suppose that they were all parts of the "same" (very long) paper, which the editors broke out into smaller pieces, for convenience.

Comment: The fall 1963 issue of the Pacific Journal of Mathematics was also filled by one set of authors, but that's because the Feit-Thompson theorem needed a whole journal issue.

Answer (score 10):

This case is not famous at all, but I think it deserves to become at least better known, so...

Beso Pachuashvili, gifted mathematician who passed away this year, is hardly known to anybody. His insights into Hopf algebra theory and monoidal categories still await proper understanding. Most notably he had envisioned certain variant of the fact that in commutative monoids of a monoidal category tensor becomes coproduct for other kinds of limits. In case of equalizers, this opened up one possible approach to the construction of cohomologies in monoidal categories. In mid eighties he had some interaction with Drinfeld on the topic, I wonder if Drinfeld can recall what information did they exchange back then.

The entire [issue 2 of Volume 72 of the Journal of Pure and Applied algebra](https://www.sciencedirect.com/journal/journal-of-pure-and-applied-algebra/vol/72/issue/2) (from 1991) is occupied by his two papers: "Cohomologies and extensions in monoidal categories" (doi:[10.1016/0022-4049(91)90027-Y](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-4049%2891%2990027-Y)) and "Some properties of cohomologies in monoidal categories" (doi:[10.1016/0022-4049(91)90028-Z](https://doi.org/10.1016/0022-4049%2891%2990028-Z)).

Answer (score 10):

In the first issue of Fundamenta Mathematicae, 1920, Wacław Sierpiński has 13 single-authored papers and 1 joint with Stefan Mazurkiewicz. In the same issue Mazurkiewicz has 3 addtional single-authored papers. Kazimierz (Casimir) Kuratowski has 3 single-authored papers and 1 joint with Zygmunt Janiszewski (a posthumous publication for the latter). The papers are not parts of bigger ones. Sierpiński also contributed several open problems to the first issue (one jointly with his student Tadeusz Felsztyn); Mazurkiewicz (alone) and Kuratowski (jointly with Bronisław Knaster) contributed 1 problem each.

Sierpiński and  Mazurkiewicz also were editors-in-chief of the journal at the time, taking over after the death of Janiszewski, who got the idea of the journal and prepared the first issue for print.
Fundamenta were supposed to concentrate on set theory and topology, the specialties of  the still-new Polish school of mathematics, so it is natural that the specialized journal featured so many contributions by then-active top Polish mathematicians. Especially the first issue, which was also meant as a kind of an introduction of the Polish school to the broader mathematical community. But even in later pre-war issues there are often multiple papers by Sierpiński and/or other authors.

The papers can be viewed and downloaded for free at https://www.impan.pl/en/publishing-house/journals-and-series/fundamenta-mathematicae/all/1

Answer (score 8):

Leonhard Euler (1707-1783) published frequently in the journals of the St Petersburg Academy, usually several papers per issue. This continued even after his death, as he had a substantial backlog of mathematics - the final paper appeared in 1830. These represent about half of his published work.

https://scholarlycommons.pacific.edu/euler-spap/ has an index, from his first such paper

> *Problematis traiectoriarum reciprocarum solutio* (1729). Commentarii academiae scientiarum Petropolitanae, 2:90-111.

to his last

> *Intégration d'une espèce remarqable d'équation différentielle dans l'analyse des fonctions à deux variables* (1830). Mémoires de l'académie des sciences de St.-Petersbourg 11:131-137.

There are several issues where Euler was the only contributor in the mathematical section. Note that in the actual journal texts, the tables of contents attribute several papers to *Eiusd.*, short for *eiusdem*, meaning the same as above; typically, that is *L. Euleri*.

The topics are sometimes closely related. In 1751 his papers include 88 pages on integration of rational differential forms, followed by another paper of 51 pages presenting an easier method for the same. But his other two papers in the same issue are some conjectures in number theory, and another on the motion of fluids under heat.

Answer (score 7):

Abel had [two](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PID=PPN243919689_0001%7Clog6) [papers](http://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/img/?PID=PPN243919689_0001%7Clog12) in the first issue of [Volume 1](https://www.digizeitschriften.de/dms/toc/?PID=PPN243919689_0001) of Crelle's Journal. A look through the Table of Contents of that volume will turn up several other instances of an author with more than one paper in an issue.

Comment: If you go to de Gruyter's pages for the articles that Abel wrote 194 years ago, then you can have the pleasure of forking out €60 to look at them, to make sure the publisher is sufficiently rewarded for their hard work ... oh wait.

Comment: Volume 1 also has a number of other Abel articles in other issues, but I'm not sure early Crelle's journal is a good comparison :-) Where else would mathematicians publish their work in those days? I think only the scientific academies (France, Royal Soc. London, Berlin,...) would have had the interest in such material.

Answer (score 6):

Not sure this counts, it's a famous one ... A. Einstein had 3 papers in Annalen der Physik 1905, Folge 4, Band 17: On pages 132, 549 and 891. Now, there's also another overall numbering in which this corresponds to Volume 322, in which these are assigned to different "issues", but I'm not sure whether those correspond to how the articles were distributed originally ...

Comment: The papers are available in the original German and in translation here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Annus_Mirabilis_papers#Primary_sources (look at papers 1–3). There is something weird with the referencing, with the middle paper being assigned to volume 322, but the first and the third volume 17 (!!)

Comment: In case anyone is wondering, "Folge 4" means something roughly like "4th series", and the numbering that puts the papers in vol. 322 rather than "4th series vol. 17" ignores this distinction and counts all volumes from the very beginning in 1799. I suspect this latter numbering is a more modern invention to prevent confusion between the series (Wikipedia notes this was a problem in practice!).

Comment: @DavidRoberts - The masthead prefacing the papers in the original already mentions in small print "volume 322 of the entire series", but I have not found any mention of "issues" in the original, so I'm not sure whether the "issues" are more modern. This may be hard to settle - already bound entire volumes of the annus mirabilis are missing from many libraries due to theft, and I don't know of anywhere that might have the material unbound. Certainly the "issue covers" that Wiley is displaying now are of a more recent provenance.

Comment: By the way, "Folge 4" is better translated as "sequence 4" to distinguish from the wording "der ganzen Reihe" = "of the entire series". This follows precisely the mathematical nomenclature - "Folge"="sequence", "Reihe"="series".

Comment: Yes I was going to say Einstein.  He was highly productive and most of have been putting multiple papers in the same journal when he was developing GR.

Comment: @MichaelEngelhardt yeah, I know Folge means sequence, but I was thinking of how English-language journals work. Compare the Annals of Mathematics second series (https://meta.mathoverflow.net/questions/3257/annals-of-mathematics-why-second-series/3258). Einstein's own papers from around the time cite his 1905 papers as being in volume 17, so I would guess that's the original. For instance, a 1906 paper on Brownian motion cites the 1905 one as "Ann. d. Phys., 17, p. 549, 1905.", no issue number mentioned, but that may just be a style thing.

Answer (score 6):

Edoardo Ballico published (until now) 404 articles in the International Journal of Pure and Applied Mathematics. He published many times two or more articles in the same issue.

For instance, in 2009 he published four articles in "Int. J. Pure Appl. Math. 57 (2009), no. 4,"

Comment: Seems like he has kept this journal in business single-handed!

Answer (score 3):

This is a physics example rather than a mathematics example, but Albert Einstein did this many times.  I believe on many occasions he in fact published multiple papers in the same issue of the same journal for different journals (often doing this several times in one year).

For example, someone above gives the example of the papers he published in 1905 but in fact in that same year, he also published multiple small review articles in the same issue of Beiblätter zu den Annalen der Physik on multiple occasions.

He likely did this again many other times although I don't have time to trawl through all the journal articles as he published more than 260: for more information, see the [Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_scientific_publications_by_Albert_Einstein).

As another theoretical physics example, I think Edward Witten has also done this at least once.  For example, [Global aspects of current algebra](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0550321383900639) and [Current algebra, baryons, and quark confinement](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/abs/pii/0550321383900640) are two separate papers, both of them published in Issue 2 of Volume 223 of Nuclear Physics B.  He may also have done this with more mathematical papers in Communications in Mathematical Physics but I can't remember.

Comment: Since this is community wiki, you could consider merging your answer with the other one about Einstein.